# Is my proof for this fact correct?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, gcd-and-lcm

The thing ought to be proven

> Let $a$ and $b$ be nonzero integers that are relatively prime, and let $c$ be an integer. Show that $ax+by=c$ has an integer solution.

My postulated proof that ought to be right

> Let $a$ and $b$ be nonzero integers such that $\gcd(a,b)=1$, and let $c$ be an integer. Since $\gcd(a,b)=1$, it follows that the smallest positive linear combination of $a$ and $b$ (which will call $d$) is equal to $\gcd(a,b)=1$, i.e. $d=as+bt=1$. Therefore $a(cs)+b(ct)=c$, hence $ax+by=c$ has an integer solution.

Is my proof correct? How shall I ameliorate it?

Comment: One of the most interesting things with maths, is the fact that ," you rarely need someone else to tell you if your answer is correct or not. You have come up with a solution to the problem, so go back to the problem and see if it actually works."

Comment: If you are saying: "it follows that the smallest positive ...is equal to ...$1$" then you are using the lemma of [Bezout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity). You should at least mention that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is correct, *provided* that you are allowed to assume the smallest linear combination of two coprime integers is $1$. If you can, then you're fine.

Comment: So I'm fine ... :)